# How to include apache commons lang3 in XCode with J2ObjC

Tags: java, xcode, j2objc

Trying to get my first j2objc project up and running in XCode. I have a few .java files and one of them references string functions in the apache commons library. I'm getting an error that says:

> Package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist

I can't work out where I'm supposed to tell the project to look at the apache folder - or do I include the .jar files I need directly? I've tried adding the commons.lang3 dir to `Framework Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only include source-code not .jar files.

Of course the source of apache commons is available here: [apache commons lang source-code](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang), which can be included with your project.